# Executor executes twice in a row

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, thread-safety

I have a single thread executor for counting a duration:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService updateTime = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

And it's executed based on a boolean property that is being changed only once if a user press a button:

```
gameStarted.addListener((e) -> {updateTime.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::calculateDuration, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);});
```

But it counts twice as fast as it should and indeed when I add `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());` to the `calculateDuration` method I see the same thread (`pool-2-thread-1`) is there twice every time.

What's even more odd is that if I remove the listener and start the executor like this:

```
updateTime.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::calculateDuration, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Then it runs at the correct rate and the thread enters the method once every time, but I have to use a trigger to start the executor because it isn't supposed to run before the game starts.

What can be the reason for executor to run twice as fast?

Comment: Most likely, the listener was called twice and you have two scheduled tasks. For example when you press a button you can get a button down and a button up event.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yeah you're right, `gameStarted.addListener(e -> {System.out.print(123);});` this prints `123` twice... that's strange.

Comment: Most likely you are getting two different events. Like key-pressed and key-released. or mouse clicked and mouse released.

Comment: I added a print to the `onAction` of the button, and it prints only once, so we reach this line: `gameManager.gameStartedProperty().setValue(true);` only once in all of the code... @PeterLawrey

Comment: Ok I found it, I was subscribing the listener twice, move it to the ctor and now it's fine.